# embeddedmap of strings not working after 2.2

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I had been developing some base queries for about 6 months prior to the release of 2.2

```
CREATE CLASS Flag_Definitions EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY Flag_Definitions.V_status EMBEDDEDMAP STRING
CREATE PROPERTY Flag_Definitions.V_branding EMBEDDEDMAP STRING
CREATE PROPERTY Flag_Definitions.Block_type EMBEDDEDMAP STRING

CREATE VERTEX Flag_Definitions SET title = "developer reference for all data flags", V_status = {"ACTIVE":"Normal active record", "SUSPENDED":"Currently inactive record","DELETED":"Discontinued record maintained for archiving"}, Block_type = {"Prop":"Holds text from a data object property","HTML":"Holds basic HTML for content","Container":"Holds other blocks"}
```

but now I'm getting this error in studio

```
{"errors":[{"code":400,"reason":400,"content":"Map found but entries are not defined as :\r\n\tDB name=\"TestDB\""}]}
```

From console, the phrasing is slightly different

```
Map found but entries are not defined as <key>:<value>
```

Either way, the format 'SET mapfield = {"key":"val"}' no longer seems to be working, and I can't find an explanation. I even looked into the [orient code on github](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/sql/OSQLHelper.java) (line 118), but, having 2 parts, the format should be passing the check on line 117.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one, it has nothing to do with the Flag_Definitions object, but I had a default status flag being applied to all created vertices

```
CREATE PROPERTY V.flags EMBEDDEDMAP STRING
ALTER PROPERTY V.flags DEFAULT {"status":"ACTIVE"}
```

The issue is the DEFAULT, which needs to be

```
DEFAULT '{"status":"ACTIVE"}'
```

Similarly, I had to change 
`DEFAULT sysdate()` to `DEFAULT "sysdate()"`